# How to integrate instagram sign in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, instagram, instagram-api

I'm want to integrate sign in through instagram in my app

currently I'm using below code

```
Future<Token> getToken(String appId, String appSecret) async {
  Stream<String> onCode = await _server();
  String url =
      "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=$appId&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8585&"
      "response_type=code&scope=basic";
  final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(url);
  final String code = await onCode.first;
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
      "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
      body: {"client_id": appId, "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8585", "client_secret": appSecret,
        "code": code, "grant_type": "authorization_code"});
  flutterWebviewPlugin.close();
  return new Token.fromMap(json.decode(response.body));
}

Future<Stream<String>> _server() async {
  final StreamController<String> onCode = new StreamController();
  HttpServer server =
  await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 8585);
  server.listen((HttpRequest request) async {
    final String code = request.uri.queryParameters["code"];
    request.response
      ..statusCode = 200
      ..headers.set("Content-Type", ContentType.html.mimeType)
      ..write("<html><h1>You can now close this window</h1></html>");
    await request.response.close();
    await server.close(force: true);
    onCode.add(code);
    await onCode.close();
  });
  return onCode.stream;
}
```

I'm able to login trough above code in Instagram

but i'm getting below error after sign in

[image]

Also i have added support for `localhost:8585` in my `info.plist` file

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost:8585</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: The remaining Instagram Legacy API permission ("Basic Permission") was disabled on June 29, 2020. As of June 29, third-party apps no longer have access to the Legacy API.

Comment: Did you try this https://pub.dev/packages/simple_auth_flutter

Comment: Have you tried this URL: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=$appId&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8585&response_type=code ?

Comment: @Goku did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Upon seeing your code, I believe you are following [this blog posts](https://medium.com/hackernoon/instagram-authentication-with-flutter-df6424d2d56c) implementation. Upon checking, it uses the "Instagram Legacy API permission ("Basic Permission")". AFAIK and as mentioned in the comment section that it was disabled last June, 2020.

Here is the [full text](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) about this:

> ### Update
>
> The remaining Instagram Legacy API permission ("Basic Permission") was
> disabled on June 29, 2020. As of June 29, third-party apps no longer
> have access to the Legacy API. To avoid disruption of service to your
> app and business, developers previously using the Legacy API should
> instead rely on [**Instagram Basic Display
> API**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api)
> and [**Instagram Graph
> API**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-graph-api). Please
> request approval for required permissions through the [**App
> Review**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/) process.
>
> **Legacy API user identifier available on Basic Display API until September 30, 2020**.
> To assist with migration, we have temporarily
> made the unique user identifier from the Legacy API - ig_id -
> available on Basic Display API. However, the ig_id field will be
> deprecated on Basic Display API on September 30, 2020, so please
> ensure you are using other fields (e.g. the Facebook "id" field) or
> your own unique identifier for your users. See our developer
> documentation
> [**here**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api#legacy-ids)
> to learn more.
>
> **User Token Generator**
> If you're only using the Legacy API to generate tokens in order to display your Instagram Feed on a personal
> website, you can use the Instagram Basic Display API's [**User Token
> Generator**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview#user-token-generator)
> to continue generating tokens. The User Token Generator does not
> require App Review, but it will only work for your owned Instagram
> accounts (i.e. accounts for which you know the login credentials).
> Refer to the developer documentation
> [**here**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview#user-token-generator)
> to learn more. If you're using the Legacy API to display multiple
> accounts on your website, then you must apply for permissions to
> [**Instagram Basic Display
> API**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api)
> via App Review. If you're using the Legacy API for any other use case,
> you must apply for permissions on the [**Instagram Graph API
> platform**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-graph-api)
> via App Review.
>
> **More Tips**
> For more guidance on getting through our App Review process, please see [**this blog
> post**](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2020/03/10/final-reminder-Instagram-legacy-api-platform-disabled-mar-31/).
> For more tips and tools, check out our [**App Review Rejection Results
> Guide**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/rejection-results-guide),
> [**Common App
> Review**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/common-rejection-reasons)
> [**Rejection
> Reasons**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/common-rejection-reasons)
> and [**Developer Tools page**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools).
> We also encourage you to leverage the [**Facebook Developer Community
> Forum**](https://developers.facebook.com/community) - it's a
> tremendously helpful resource for communicating and connecting with
> developers across the world.

Check out [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Emypa7YLAhI&t=4s) for the new guide on how to get Instagram access token.